# Daily and hourly power consumption from accumulated record make mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-visualization

I am calculate hourly and daily data for a power meter with accumulated record energy consumption as below:

| Device | Time | kWH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Meter 1 | 12 May 2022 21:05:00 | 900 |
| Meter 1 | 12 May 2022 21:20:00 | 930 |
| Meter 1 | 12 May 2022 21:55:00 | 950 |
| Meter 1 | 12 May 2022 22:05:00 | 1000 |
| Meter 1 | 12 May 2022 22:55:00 | 1050 |
| Meter 1 | 13 May 2022 00:05:00 | 1200 |

I try to group by time of date, and date. But after that data look not make sense as below:

```
Hourly report:
Meter 1|12 May 2022 21:00:00    |50 (950-900)
Meter 1|12 May 2022 22:00:00    |50 (1050-100)
Meter 1|13 May 2022 00:00:00    |0 (only 1 data)

Daily report:
Meter 1|12 May 2022         |150 (1050-900)
Meter 1|13 May 2022         |0 (only 1 data)
```

**-> Hourly and daily is not equal for day 12 May 2022**

So I would like to find a method to calculate as expect data below:

```
Hourly report:
Meter 1|12 May 2022 21:00:00    |50 (950-900)
Meter 1|12 May 2022 22:00:00    |100 (1050-950)
Meter 1|13 May 2022 00:00:00    |150 (1200-1050)

Daily report:
Meter 1|12 May 2022         |150 (1050-900)
Meter 1|13 May 2022         |150 (1200-1050)
```

I hope to find out method to solve the issue mismatch from new hour data/last hour data, new day data/last day data.

Currently I am using python and pandas.

Comment: Your data contains no information at all about consumption on May 13.  Start of May 12 is 900.  Start of May 13 in 1200.  Thus, May 12 should be 300. May 13 should be 0.  Right?  And we can't tell you very much without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, your proposal data calculation is make sense. I think I can follow the statement that: hourly = first new hour - first last hour; first new day - first last day = daily. So in that case, hourly will be: hour 21: 1000-900 = 100, hour 22: 1200-100 = 200. and daily will be: day 12: 1200-900 = 300.

Comment: I am try to find the method first so the code is not completed yet. BTW if you familiar with summarize accumulated data by hourly and daily.. please introduce to me some example to solve using python + pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is aggregate per `Device` and hours/days in [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html), get difference per `Device` and replace first value by substract last anf first value:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df1 = df.groupby(['Device', pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='Time')])['kWH'].agg(['first','last'])

df1 = df1.groupby(level=0)['last'].diff().fillna(df1['last'].sub(df1['first'])).reset_index(name='hour diff')
print (df1)
    Device                Time  hour diff
0  Meter 1 2022-05-12 21:00:00       50.0
1  Meter 1 2022-05-12 22:00:00      100.0
2  Meter 1 2022-05-13 00:00:00      150.0

df2 = df.groupby(['Device', pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='Time')])['kWH'].agg(['first','last'])

df2 = df2.groupby(level=0)['last'].diff().fillna(df2['last'].sub(df2['first'])).reset_index(name='day diff')
print (df2)
    Device       Time   day diff
0  Meter 1 2022-05-12      150.0
1  Meter 1 2022-05-13      150.0
```

Comment: This is exactly the right approach, but the way his data is organized means this may not produce the results he wants.  Looking at his example, those 150 units used in the last interval should rightly be credited to the previous day,  I'm not sure there's a rock-solid way to handle that without iterating.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. That is the way I am finding. Thanks Tim also. Actually my previous concern is sum of hour is not equal to sum of day. so this approach solved my problem!